# macOS: copying a file on a SMB filesystem

Tags: swift, macos, smb, cifs

I have a RAID disk which makes its files available over CIFS/SMB. If I copy a large file (600MB) from one location on the volume to another location on the same volume using Finder (i.e., option-drag the file), it only takes a second or two.

If I try to do the same operation programmatically using the code below, it takes upwards of a minute.

```
let source = URL(filePath: "/Volumes/media/tmp/bigfile.dat")
let dest = URL(filePath: "/Volumes/media/finaldest/file.dat")
try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: source, to: dest)
```

My theory is that Finder can detect that the source and destination are on the same network volume and uses a special SMB API to do the copying server side, without having to move a bunch of bytes back and forth over the network. `FileManager` does not have this same optimization.

Does anybody have suggestions on how I can make my program behave like the Finder does?

Comment: Maybe try changing directory to `/Volumes/media` first, then copying`tmp/bigfile.dat` to `finaldest/file.dat` to see if it needs a hand working out that they are on the same volume. Just a thought.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but after doing `changeCurrentDirectoryPath(_:)` and updating the copy to use `copyItem(atPath:toPath:)` it made no difference.

Comment: Have you read this [article on developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/122792)?

Comment: @burnsi thanks for the link, but that appears to apply only to iOS; my app runs on macOS.